# Change operating system on boot up

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot

I'm trying to figure out how to get the menu to change your operating system on computer start up.

I Have windows 7 & I'm trying to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing Ubuntu then, during your installation you will be asked where to store your boot loader.

If you save your boot loader in Windows 7 partition, then you will get selection menu of operating systems.

you can configure your start up operating selection time in windows from

MyComputer->Properties->Advanced System Settings ->Advanced (Tab) -> Start up and Recovery setting.

Answer (score 0):

Simply boot up the system with the Ubuntu installation CD.

It will walk you through the options and install the Ubuntu OS.

Once installed and after a reboot, you'll be asked which way to go - i.e., Ubuntu or Windows.

This is a side-by-side option. But you can also install Ubuntu OR Windows on top of a virtual machine. This way you can go between operating systems without a reboot.

And just to the point, the program that allows OS choices at start up is called GRUB. By default, if you follow my method of side-by-side installation, GRUB gets installed for you.